# A script to find a section of a formula in a group of cells and replace it with input from the user

Tags: google-apps-script, replace, find

I've put together an attendance google sheet that pulls data from weekly attendance tabs to a master sheet with all the weeks together. So far the master sheet is set so that more weeks can be added by pressing a button by duplicating the first week of the master sheet and appending it to the last column of the sheet.

So what I need help with is in the cells of the new duplicated week find a portion of the formula, in the case would be the dates of the old week tab `'9/21-9/25'` (the full formula is `='9/14-9/18'!$E$5`) and replace it with the new week inputted by the user with a prompt, example `'9/28-10/2'`.

This is the code I've come up with so far.

```
function newWeek() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var rowCol = sheet.getLastRow();
  var maxCols = sheet.getMaxColumns();

  // Number of columns to duplicate//
  var numCols = 15
  //Selects the previous week//
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, lastCol - 14, rowCol, 15);
  //Inserts columns for next week//
  sheet.insertColumnsAfter(lastCol, numCols);
  //Copies previous weeks properties into new columns//
  range.copyTo(sheet.getRange(1, lastCol + 1, rowCol, 15));
}
```

And if you think of an easier solution for what I am trying to do please let me know. It needs to be just a press of the button and enter the new dates and everything is created and pulled from the new week tab.

Comment: If the answer from @TheMaster below is not answering your question - I'm struggling to understand the details of what you need and what your original sheet looks like. Would you be able to post some test data on a spreadsheet with your code? Or a step by step flow of what you would like to accomplish with an example of the input data and result? (also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is a helpful read)

Comment: @TheMaster was able to answered my question. I needed to change the date range part of the formula I was using to pull data from another sheet where the data range is it's title. When a new sheet is created with a different date range as the title I wanted to be able to update the formula in the master sheet to pull data from the new sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class [TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder) can be used to search and replace within formulas using [`matchFormulaText()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#matchFormulaText(Boolean)) method:

#### Snippet:

```
range.createTextFinder('9/21-9/25')
  .matchFormulaText(true)
  .replaceAllWith('9/28-10/2')
```